# What is wrong with my javascript code? It asks the first prompt but doesnt do the if/else function

Tags: javascript

I am more or less new at javascript and i am trying to make a little fun program kind of thing and i want it to ask for your name and then tell you something in return. Here is the code:

```
var name = (prompt("What is your name? Capitalization matters!"));

if (name === Random name) {

    return("Random name :D, I think you already know who sent you this, but if not it's me  :D.");
}
else {

return("Is that really your name? If so, that shows how popular I am haha. If that's not your name, LIAR!");
    }
```

Comment: what is `Random name` here : `if (name === Random name) ` ?

Comment: `name === Random name` ? Where did you find this ?

Comment: Is this in a function?  If so, could you show us your code that calls it?

Comment: And what should happen? All this code says is "return a string". It won't output it unless you have specified that elsewhere.

Comment: uhh i just put random name there in replacement for whatever name the person puts... i plan to put a specific name there but i just decided to take the name out for now.

Comment: This is all my code so far... i didnt even realize that i had to call it afterwards thank you!

Comment: so what would i put from here? if you guys dont mind helping me more than you already have?

Answer (score 4):

You can only `return` from a function, and what you posted is not a function. You can use `alert` instead:

```
var name = prompt("What is your name? Capitalization matters!");
if (name === "John") {
    alert("Random name :D, I think you already know who sent you this, but if not it's me  :D.");
} else {
    alert("Is that really your name? If so, that shows how popular I am haha. If that's not your name, LIAR!");
}
```

If you want to make it a function:

```
function checkName() {
    var name = prompt("What is your name? Capitalization matters!");
    if (name === "John") {
        return "Random name :D, I think you already know who sent you this, but if not it's me  :D.";
    } else {
        return "Is that really your name? If so, that shows how popular I am haha. If that's not your name, LIAR!";
    }
}
alert(checkName());
```

Comment: both of your explanatiosn maek sense but when i try to exectue either one, it still just asks me the prompt but it doesnt tell me the "alert" or "return" part

Comment: Both work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mr6u3/. There must be a syntax error in your code stopping the execution (check your js console to verify)

Comment: Whats a js console? sorry for my impotence

Comment: @user2420989 That's part of the developer tools most browsers provide, and it's really useful. The F12 key usually opens the console. If it doesn't, check the browser's menus for the developer tools (on Firefox, use the Firebug extension).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the user entered "Random Name" then you need to enclose the string in quotes as you do when you print it:

```
var name = (prompt("What is your name? Capitalization matters!"));    
if (name === "Random name") {
    return("Random name :D, I think you already know who sent you this, but if not it's me  :D.");
} else {   
    return("Is that really your name? If so, that shows how popular I am haha. If that's not your name, LIAR!");
}
```

Just my guess, tho.

Comment: that seems to be one step closer but it still doesnt do everything. so far it has only asked me the prompt but it doesnt go any farther than that.

Comment: But you haven't shown us how you're using it. And is it a function at all? Otherwise, you shouldn't be using `return`.

Comment: I didnt intend to make it as a function. But im trying to use it so that it asks you What is your name (which is working) and then depending on what name you put in, you get a response (which isnt working). And by any chance do you know what i should use in place ofr response?